# Storing data in memory

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, pojo

I have `"TABLE A"` in database which contains 3 columns `"COL 1" , "COL 2" and "COL 3"` with around `1000000` (1 Million) records.

Against this table i have mapped a simple `POJO` lets say `"ClassA"` with 3 instance variables `"var1" , "var2" , "var3"` and also defined there `set()` and `get()` methods .

My application contains simple JSPs , Servlets and POJOs with no fancy frameworks and no other technologies .

What I actually want is that when first time my application is going to be deployed on the Application Server and the very first request which it receives , only for that request (only 1 time) my Servlet is going to get the 1 Million records from `TABLE A` , maps the ClassA with these records and starts populating the objects for `ClassA` and keep them in a Vector or an `ArrayList` , as you might have understood that my `Vector/ArrayList` will now contain 1 Million objects with each object representing a `record/tupple` in the `"TableA"` .

OK , now come to the real and difficult part , I want this `Vector/ArrayList` to be `stored/persisted/added` to the application context or to the VM or to any other memory storage location (which actually I do not know) , so that each time my JSP `pages/Servlets` are accessing the object in memory of getting data and not hitting the database every time .

Comment: why not use an in-memory database such as hsqldb, which will act as a cache and you can use your favorite SQL statements - populate it on your application initialization time. Other option is to use cache solution such as JBoss infinispan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use **Java Caching System**([see here](http://jakarta.apache.org/jcs/index.html)) or **Ehcache** ([see here](http://ehcache.org/)) to store data in cache, **Inversion of Control** in **Spring** also helps in some way but not sure whether it would help to store 1 million data in heap, as heap memory is limited.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need caching, if I get you right.
I would recommend to take a look on [EHcache](http://ehcache.org/) or [Infinispan](http://www.jboss.org/infinispan) here.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for some way to cache your objects.

You may want to look at [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/)

or,

since you have large objects you can look at implementing Object Repository like,  [noDB](http://code.google.com/p/nodb/)