# How to Store Data Without a File or Server in Java?

Tags: java, variables, storage

So, forgive me if I'm too ambitious and this isn't possible, but I am wondering if it's possible to like set a variable while my program is running, have it closed, have the computer shutdown, and have the app start up again, and have that variable the same as it was.

I've only ever heard of people using servers or files, and so I'm wondering if this is possible.

Comment: I would suggest looking into the concept of volatile and not volatile storage to get a better understanding of what you're asking and why it won't work without some kind of file

Comment: you can try to send/receive  your data to a server .Check this question if is helpfull. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680259/using-sockets-to-send-and-receive-data

Comment: @bembas I explicitly said that I did not want to use a server.

Comment: i dont think its possible then

Comment: Maybe use the RAM? Check it out here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313862/storing-data-in-memory]

Comment: You need to store your data somewhere, so I think you won't get around using a file (may it be hidden away in something like an `AppData` folder), or a server.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to store a variable forever in side your application. You'll have to either store in the HDD or send a web request to a server where they store values for you.

Build your own website using PHP. There are many free web hosting services. Host your website and your database. Send a HTTP request and you may write a JSON response from your server side.

If that's a lot of trouble, file saving method would be the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write the state of your application out to disk somehow, there's no way around that. Note though this doesn't necessarily have to be a disk on the same machine that your app is running on.

Usually this is accomplished (in the Java land) by using a dB (mysql for instance), then using either plain JDBC to fire off SQL queries, or using an ORM such as hibernate (which will then use SQL underneath.)

You can use something called object serialisation to save the state of your objects to disk directly, and then recall them later. However, this is generally considered an ill advised, obsolete approach (and Oracle are planning to remove it entirely in a future version of Java, so definitely one to stay away from.)